# How do I extract the weights of my quantized model for use on hardware?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, quantization

EDIT: attaching some code to help generate similar results (appended at end)

I have a really small model with architecture `[2, 3, 6]` where the hidden layer uses ReLU and it's a softmax activation for multiclass classification. Trained offline and statically quantized later to qint8. What I would like to do now is extract the weights so I can use them on other hardware via matrix multiplication/addition. The problem I'm encountering is it doesn't seem to behave as expected. Take for instance this GraphModule output of state_dict():

```py
OrderedDict([('input_layer_input_scale_0', tensor(0.0039)),
             ('input_layer_input_zero_point_0', tensor(0)),
             ('input_layer.scale', tensor(0.0297)),
             ('input_layer.zero_point', tensor(0)),
             ('input_layer._packed_params.dtype', torch.qint8),
             ('input_layer._packed_params._packed_params',
              (tensor([[-0.1180,  0.1180],
                       [-0.2949, -0.5308],
                       [-3.3029, -7.5496]], size=(3, 2), dtype=torch.qint8,
                      quantization_scheme=torch.per_tensor_affine, scale=0.05898105353116989,
                      zero_point=0),
               Parameter containing:
               tensor([-0.4747, -0.3563,  7.7603], requires_grad=True))),
             ('out.scale', tensor(1.5963)),
             ('out.zero_point', tensor(243)),
             ('out._packed_params.dtype', torch.qint8),
             ('out._packed_params._packed_params',
              (tensor([[  0.4365,   0.4365, -55.4356],
                       [  0.4365,   0.0000,   1.3095],
                       [  0.4365,   0.0000, -13.9680],
                       [  0.4365,  -0.4365,   4.3650],
                       [  0.4365,   0.4365,  -3.0555],
                       [  0.4365,   0.0000,  -1.3095],
                       [  0.4365,   0.0000,   3.0555]], size=(7, 3), dtype=torch.qint8,
                      quantization_scheme=torch.per_tensor_affine, scale=0.43650051951408386,
                      zero_point=0),
               Parameter containing:
               tensor([ 19.2761,  -1.0785,  14.2602, -22.3171,  10.1059,   7.2197, -11.7253],
                      requires_grad=True)))])
```

If I directly access the weights the way I think I should like so:

```py
input_weights = np.array(
[[-0.1180,  0.1180],
 [-0.2949, -0.5308],
 [-3.3029, -7.5496]])
inputs_scale = 0.05898105353116989
inputs_zero_point = 0

W1=np.clip(np.round(input_weights/inputs_scale+ inputs_zero_scale), -127, 128)
b1=np.clip(np.round(np.array([-0.4747, -0.3563,  7.7603])/inputs_scale + inputs_zer_scale), -127, 128)

output_weights = np.array(
[[  0.4365,   0.4365, -55.4356],
 [  0.4365,   0.0000,   1.3095],
 [  0.4365,   0.0000, -13.9680],
 [  0.4365,  -0.4365,   4.3650],
 [  0.4365,   0.4365,  -3.0555],
 [  0.4365,   0.0000,  -1.3095],
 [  0.4365,   0.0000,   3.0555]])

outputs_scale=0.43650051951408386
outputs_zero_point=0
W1=np.clip(np.round(output_weights/outputs_scale+ outputs_zero_scale), -127, 128)
W2=np.clip(np.round(np.array([ 19.2761,  -1.0785,  14.2602, -22.3171,  10.1059,   7.2197, -11.7253])/outputs_scale + outputs_zero_scale), -127, 128)
```

And then I give it some data:

```
inputs = np.array(
       [[1.  , 1.  ], # class 0 example
       [1.  , 0.  ], # class 1 example
       [0.  , 1.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.9 ],
       [0.  , 0.75],
       [0.  , 0.25]]) # class 6 example
```

Where each row is an example, then I would expect to be able to do matrix multiplication and argmax over the rows to get the result. However, doing that gives me this:

```
>>> (ReLU((inputs @ W1.T) + b1) @ W2.T + b2).argmax(axis=0)
array([0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3])
```

which is not right.
And when I test accuracy of the quantized model in pytorch it's high enough that it should get all examples correct here. So what am I misunderstanding in terms of accessing these weights/bias?

EDIT: adding code to help people mess around with quantization. Now technically it doesn't matter how this code is generated - an OrderedDict of the quantized model will remain similar. If you want to mess around with it, here is some code to generate a model and quantize it on the XOR problem. Note that I'm using a multiclass classification still to help stick to my original model. Anyway.... here you go...

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import random
import copy
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.ao.quantization.quantize_fx import prepare_fx, convert_fx
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset
from pytorch_lightning.callbacks.progress import RichProgressBar
from pytorch_lightning.callbacks.early_stopping import EarlyStopping
import pytorch_lightning as pl

class XORModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, h: int):
        super().__init__()
        self.input_layer = nn.Linear(2, h)
        self.out = nn.Linear(h, 2)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.input_layer(x)
        out = F.relu(out)
        out = self.out(out)
        return out

class LitModel(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, model: XORModel):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = model
    
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.model(x)
    
    def _generic_step(self, batch, batch_idx, calc_metric: bool = False):
        x, y = batch
        out = self.model(x)
        if calc_metric:
            with torch.no_grad():
                soft = F.softmax(out, dim=-1)
                metric = (soft.argmax(-1).ravel() == y.ravel()).float().mean()
                self.log('Accuracy', metric, prog_bar=True)
        
        loss = F.cross_entropy(out, y)
        return loss
    
    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        loss = self._generic_step(batch, batch_idx)
        self.log('train_loss', loss, prog_bar=True)
        return loss
    
    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        loss = self._generic_step(batch, batch_idx, calc_metric=True)
        self.log('val_loss', loss, prog_bar=True)
        return loss
    
    def configure_optimizers(self):
        return torch.optim.Adam(self.model.parameters())

def get_accuracy(model: XORModel, seed: int):
    dataset = make_dataset(1000, 1000, False, seed)
    
    model.eval()
    ret = []
    with torch.no_grad():
        for X, y in dataset:
            out = F.softmax(model(X), dim=-1).argmax(-1)
            ret.append((out.cpu().numpy() == y.numpy()).mean())
    model.train()
    return np.array(ret).mean()

def make_dataset(samples: int, batch_size: int, shuffle: bool, seed: int):
    inputs, outputs = [], []
    rng = random.Random(seed)

    for _ in range(samples):
        x0 = rng.randint(0, 1)
        x1 = rng.randint(0, 1)
        y = x0 ^ x1
        inputs.append((x0, x1))
        outputs.append(y)
    
    dataset = TensorDataset(torch.tensor(inputs, dtype=torch.float), torch.tensor(outputs, dtype=torch.long))
    dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=shuffle)
    return dataloader

def quantize_model(model: XORModel):
    model_to_quantize = copy.deepcopy(model)
    model_to_quantize.eval()
    def calibrate(m, data_loader):
        m.eval()
        with torch.no_grad():
            for x in data_loader:
                m(x)

    loader = make_dataset(1000, 1000, False, 0x42)
    sample_inputs = next(iter(loader))[0]
    qconfig_dict = {'': torch.quantization.get_default_qconfig('fbgemm')}
    prepared_model = prepare_fx(model, qconfig_dict)
    calibrate(prepared_model, sample_inputs)
    quantized_model = convert_fx(prepared_model)

    return quantized_model

if __name__ == '__main__':
    train_dataset = make_dataset(10_000, 256, True, 123456)
    val_dataset = make_dataset(500, 64, True, 0xabcd)
    test_dataset = make_dataset(1000, 1000, False, 0x1122)

    model = XORModel(3)
    lit_model = LitModel(model)
    trainer = pl.Trainer(accelerator='cpu', max_epochs=100,
                         callbacks=[
                            RichProgressBar(refresh_rate=50),
                            EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', patience=3)
                         ])
    
    trainer.fit(lit_model, train_dataset, val_dataset)
    qmodel = quantize_model(lit_model.model)
    print('accuracy of model', get_accuracy(model, 0xbeef))  # prints 1
    print('accuray of qmodel', get_accuracy(qmodel, 0xbeef)) # prints 1
```

Now assuming you save off the qmodel for later, you can look at the parameters similar to how I do by calling `qmodel.state_dict()`

Comment: Could you please clarify more this block of code `OrderedDict`? How can I reproduce this block of code?

Comment: @Hamzah technically it doesn't matter because it's just the output of my model. Unfortunately I can't add the original dataset but I did create an example you can use based on the XOR problem. This will train a model using pytorch lightning and then quantize it to int8 representation.

Comment: In the second code block, is that a typo in the last two lines, they should be w2, b2?

Comment: Inputs flow into W1 and b1 and give Z1. That Z1 would then flow to W2 and b2 in this case.

Comment: But you have two W1 calculations: `W1=np.clip(np.round(input_weights/inputs_scale+ inputs_zero_scale), -127, 128)` and also `W1=np.clip(np.round(output_weights/outputs_scale+ outputs_zero_scale), -127, 128)`

Answer (score 0):

`quantize_model()` is applied in the end. This technique reduces the quality of the predictions.
Try to look at **quantization aware training (QAT)**:
https://pytorch.org/blog/introduction-to-quantization-on-pytorch/#quantization-aware-training

Comment: Right but my point is that it works when I pass it to the quantized model. The quantization works fine but doing the math manually is resulting in something different.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the transpose. Try without it?

```
(ReLU((inputs @ W1) + b1) @ W2 + b2).argmax(axis=0)
```

Comment: This still won't result in the correct otuput.

Answer (score 0):

you are using a variable called `inputs_zero_scale` instead of inputs_zero_point and `outputs_zero_scale` instead of `outputs_zero_point` when computing the biases `b1` and `b2`.
Also you need to use `axis=1` when calling `argmax` because you want to compute the maximum over the rows, not the columns.

```
input_weights = np.array(
[[-0.1180,  0.1180],
[-0.2949, -0.5308],
[-3.3029, -7.5496]])
inputs_scale = 0.05898105353116989
inputs_zero_point = 0

W1 = np.clip(np.round(input_weights/inputs_scale+ inputs_zero_point), -127, 128)
b1 = np.clip(np.round(np.array([-0.4747, -0.3563,  7.7603])/inputs_scale + 
inputs_zero_point), -127, 128)

output_weights = np.array(
[[  0.4365,   0.4365, -55.4356],
[  0.4365,   0.0000,   1.3095],
[  0.4365,   0.0000, -13.9680],
[  0.4365,  -0.4365,   4.3650],
[  0.4365,   0.4365,  -3.0555],
[  0.4365,   0.0000,  -1.3095],
[  0.4365,   0.0000,   3.0555]])

outputs_scale=0.43650051951408386
outputs_zero_point=0
W2 = np.clip(np.round(output_weights/outputs_scale+ outputs_zero_point), -127, 128)
b2 = np.clip(np.round(np.array([ 19.2761,  -1.0785,  14.2602, -22.3171,  10.1059,   7.2197, -11.7253])/outputs_scale + outputs_zero_point), -127, 128)

inputs = np.array(
   [[1.  , 1.  ], # class 0 example
   [1.  , 0.  ], # class 1 example
   [0.  , 1.  ],
   [0.  , 0.  ],
   [0.  , 0.9 ],
   [0.  , 0.75],
   [0.  , 0.25]]) # class 6 example

print((np.maximum(0, (inputs @ W1.T) + b1) @ W2.T + b2).argmax(axis=1))
```

Comment: Even if that's the case, running the code you provided results in it printing `[0 3 4 3 3 3 3]` which goes back to thinking there is a different way to do the quantization calculations.